# How do i Fix api data not displaying with vue and axios

Tags: django, rest, vue.js

I can't seem to load the data information on the html table from the api via using vue and axios

I am adding vue as my frontend to my rest api and i have called the api correctly using axios the problem i am having is there is no data shown but the loop displays the number of lines cos i have 3 entries and the table shows 3 empty spaces but no meaningful data and there's no console error please what ami i doing wrong ?

```
<div class="body">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover dataTable ">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Article Id </th>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                    <th>Body</th>
                                    <th>Edit</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                     <th>Article Id </th>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                    <th>Body</th>
                                    <th>Edit</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                          </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr v-for="article in articles" :key="article.article_id">
                                    <td>{{ article.article_id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ article.article_title }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ article.article_body }}</td>
                                    <td><button @click="geArticle(article.article_id)" class="btn btn-round btn-primary">Edit</button></td>
                                    <td><button @click="deleteArticle(article.article_id)" class="btn btn-round btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
                                    <td></td>

                                </tr>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: "#startapp",
    data: {
        articles: [],
        // loading: false,
        currentArticle: {},
        message: null,
        currentArticle: {},
        newArticle: {'article_title': null, 'article_body': null}

    },
    mounted(){
        this.getArticles();
    },

    methods: {
        getArticles: function() {
            axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: '/api/article'

            }).then((response) => this.articles = response.data)
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

The data from the api is supposed to show the article_id, article_title and article_body but i get blank spaces and there is no error

Comment: could you pls add the api response that you get?

Comment: does your app send a request ? can you log the response ?

Comment: Based on your code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BMKLwM?editors=1011 - it should work fine

Comment: The api response is 200 it's just the data that is not showing. I can see the spaces for the data showing @Gowri

Comment: @BeniaminH it shows the same thing nothing has changed even with the new url i only get the spaces for the data but not the data and there is no error with the api

Comment: we need a response sample

Comment: here is the output https://imgur.com/a/0yxqIJP

Comment: @BeniaminH what can i do i have been trying different things none has worked

Comment: I haven't tried it, you are missing tbody, table, div close tag

Comment: and I see there is class datatable, are you using jquery datatable plugin? maybe you need to initialize it or something like that

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius thank you i have fixed it it was django templating that was causing the problem so i added delimeters to the vue code. Thank you everybody

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that is likely to go wrong especially as there are no error messages showing is forgetting to run your json-server package. This should run simultaneously as your development tools.
First run:

```
npm run json
```

While the above is still running, open another terminal and run this:

```
npm run serve
```